# Adjunction of pushforward and pullback

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $f:(X,\mathscr{O}_X)\to (Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. Then for any $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{O}_Y$-module $\mathscr{G}$, there is a natural bijection of **sets**
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F})
$$
giving the adjunction $f^*\dashv f_*$.

After some checking, I think more is true: First, we have 
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F})
$$
as $\Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)$-modules, where $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})$ has the $\Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)$-module structure given by the contraction $\Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$.

> Therefore, it leads to me concluding that there is an isomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_Y$-modules
>   $$
> f_*\mathscr{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\cong \mathscr{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F})
> $$
>   and equivalently an isomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules
>   $$
> \mathscr{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\cong f^*\mathscr{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F}).
> $$

Please correct me if I am wrong, I want to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first isomorphism seems believable: just plug in any open set $U$ on both sides. You need to check things like
$$(f^*\mathscr G)\big|_{f^{-1}U} = \left(f\big|_{f^{-1}U}\right)^* \left(\mathscr G\big|_U\right),$$
etc, because you want to use the adjunction $\left(f\big|_{f^{-1}U}\right)^* \dashv \left(f\big|_{f^{-1}U}\right)_*$.

But pulling it through the adjunction only gives you a morphism$$f^*\mathscr{H}om_{\mathcal O_Y}(\mathscr G, f_*\mathscr F) \to \mathscr{H}om_{\mathcal O_X}(f^*\mathscr G, \mathscr F).$$
You cannot expect this map to be an isomorphism (unless the counit for the adjunction is an isomorphism, which is rarely the case).

To give an example where the second map is not an isomorphism, consider  $\mathscr G = \mathcal O_Y$. Then the last morphism *is* the counit $f^*f_* \mathscr F \to \mathscr F$.

For example, consider $X = \mathbb P^1_k$, and $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$, and let $\mathscr F = \mathcal O(-1)$. Then
$$f_* \mathscr F = H^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathscr F) = 0,$$
so $f^*f_* \mathscr F = 0$. Thus, $f^*f_* \mathscr F \to \mathscr F$ is not an isomorphism, as $\mathscr F \neq 0$.

Comment: For the second morphism, we do have $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F})\otimes_{\Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)}\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ as $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$-modules. So I think we can again plug in open sets to obtain the $\mathscr{O}_X$-module isomorphism.

Comment: I don't understand where the tensor product with $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ comes from. Wasn't it already an isomorphism before any tensoring? Then surely this won't remain the case when you extend scalars. It seems to me that you are trying to use the exact same thing: the counit of the adjunction between extension and restriction of scalars along a ring homomorphism need not be an isomorphism.

Comment: Can I have an example of a module restricted and extended via tensor not isomorphic to itself?

Comment: For example by dimension reasons (if your ring homomorphism is a field extension): if $K \subseteq L$ is a finite field extension of degree $n$, then $L$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$, so the base extension $L \otimes_K L$ is $n$-dimensional over $L$ (whereas $L$ itself is one-dimensional over $L$).